# How can I automate this executable?

Tags: executable

I'm trying to write a script that will take a file as an input and run a pre-existing executable program on the file to modify its contents according to pre-set values in the script. The .exe file I am using is a very simple third-party software and has no API or libraries which I can hook on to. It has a GUI which contains a drop-down list of entries which in turn contain their values in editable textboxes. I need to select several of those entries and change their values.I have no idea if this is possible and if it is, what language would allow me to accomplish this. Any ideas to help get me started is appreciated.

Here is a picture of the executable interface. 
[image: 1]

Comment: Could you please post a link or a snippet of code. We can offer no help without something to look at.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. I've also attached a picture of the exectuable in my original post. I feel like it should be simple but I need to confirm if it is possible to edit values on an executable without any API.

Comment: 1. Check if the program has command line arguments (run from the command line with -? or --help).
2. If not, run a resource extractor program, find the dialog and write a program to run it in a shell, connect to the window and PostMessage to the controls to set the selection and submit the result.

Answer (score 0):

VBScript *might* be able to do this using `SendKeys`. See [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/automate-tasks-with-windows-script-hosts-sendkeys-method/) for a nice introduction. In the past I used it to automate `Derive` (a computer algebra system which lacked an API). Alas, my results were mixed as SendKeys is notoriously hard to use reliably. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1975180/4996248) question seems relevant.